# Induction: $n + 3 < n!$ for all $n>3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, alternative-proof

I have a proof that I am trying to prove and I am getting stuck at the inductive hypothesis. This is my theorem:

> For all real numbers $n>3$, the following is true: $n + 3 < n!$.

I have proven true for $n = 4$, and will assume true for some arbitrary value $k$, i.e.,

$$k + 3 < n!,$$

and I want to prove for $k+1$, i.e.,

$$(k+1) + 3 < (k+1)!.$$

Consider the $k+1$ term:

$$(k+1)+3 = ?$$

I am confused on how to approach the next step.

Ok here is how I am proceeding. It seems really long so if anyone has a better way let me know:
$$
=(k+3)+1
$$
$$
<(k!)+1
$$
$$
<k!+k!
$$
$$
=2k!
$$
$$
<(k+1)k!
$$
$$
=(k+1)!
$$
Therefore both sides are equivalent.

Comment: For all real numbers $n$, you're taking $n!$? Are you sure you don't mean for all natural numbers $n$?

Comment: It might be but the question states for all real numbers.

Comment: $$n((n-1)!-1)>3((3-1)!-1)=3$$
$$n!-n>3$$
$$n!>n+3$$

Comment: @NightMarcher $n!$ is only defined for nonnegative integers.

Comment: I didn't even catch that.....my teacher wrote up the question this way. Good call

Comment: This is a bad induction problem because the relationship between the two sides is so weak.  It actually requires more ingenuity to prove this way than, say, $2^n < n!$ for the same values of $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Induction is overkill here.

For $n \gt 3$ we have that $n+3 \lt n + n = 2\cdot n \lt 1\cdot 2 \cdot3\cdots (n-1) \cdot n =n!$

Comment: The problem states that it has to be a proof by induction.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to solve this problem, I'll only give you a hint.

Inductive Step: we want to show $(n+1)+3 < (n+1)!$

That's equivalent to $n+4 < (n+1)\cdot n!$ by the property of the factorial.

We can distribute: $n+4 < (n\cdot n!) + (1\cdot n!)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm still lost....I have been taught to solve for one side of the equation to solve are you proceeding in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Since by induction hypothesis,

$$k+3< k!$$

for $k>4$, multiply both sides by $(k+1)$ to get

$$(k+3)(k+1) < k! (k+1)$$

or

$$(k+3)(k+1) < (k+1)!$$

I'll leave the rest for you to think about, as a hint, remember that's an inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $k! \gt k+3$ is true:

> \begin{align*}
> \ (k+1)! &=k!\cdot(k+1)
> \\ &\gt(k+3)(k+1)
> \\ &=k^2+4k+3
> \\ &\gt k^2+k+3
> \\ &\gt (k+1)+3\ldots(\text{where}\space k\gt 3)
> \end{align*}

Comment: One of those inequalities is wrong.

Comment: @DennisMeng thanks for reminding and I correct it. Could you also tell me how to hide those contents?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n+3< n!$ and $(n+1)!\leq n+1+3$ , we see the following:

$$(n+1)!\leq n+1+3 \Rightarrow (n+1)n!\leq n+1+3 $$

$$\Rightarrow (n+1)(n+3)\leq(n+1)n!\leq n+1+3 $$

$$(n+1)(n+3)\leq (n+1)+3 \Rightarrow (n+1)(n+3)-(n+1) \leq 3$$

$$ \Rightarrow (n+1)(n+3-1)\leq 3$$

$$(n+1)(n+2)\leq 3$$

This should strike some thing s wrong... what is that?